# Any Risk in Using Static Method in IDisposable?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, memory-management, static-methods, idisposable

I have a class that implements IDisposable and I want to make some of the methods static. Would doing this have any negative impact on memory management or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any risk in calling a static method there. I'm curious, though, why you would want to. `IDisposable` should be dealing with cleaning up native resources used by the given instance. Static methods don't work on any specific instance of an object (unless you pass it as a parameter). It seems like any method you would call would be better as an instance method rather than a static one.

Comment: The method is mapping from xml to a .net type. I need to make it static because the constructor of the class does not always succeed do to app.config setting varying depending on where the app is deployed. The constructor instantiates a repository but the repository is not required within the static methods.

Comment: This allows me to unit test methods not dependent on the repository.

Answer (score 1):

No, as static methods on a class are [not involved in memory management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). As implied by static, the method has nothing to do with any given instance of the class rather, the method relates to the class as a whole.